# 403 trying to run terraform from Gitlab without json file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, terraform, impersonation, service-accounts

After a pile of troubleshooting, I managed to get my gitlab CICD pipeline to connect to GCP without requiring my service account to use a JSON key. However, I'm unable to do anything with Terraform in my pipeline using a remote statefile because of the following error:

```
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions
```

My gitlab-ci.yml file is defined as follows:

```
stages:
  - auth
  - validate

gcp-auth:
  stage: auth
  image: google/cloud-sdk:slim
  script:
    - echo ${CI_JOB_JWT_V2} > .ci_job_jwt_file
    - gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config ${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER}
      --service-account="${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"
      --output-file=.gcp_temp_cred.json
      --credential-source-file=.ci_job_jwt_file
    - gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    - gcloud auth list

tf-stuff:
  stage: validate
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
      - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  before_script:
    - export TF_LOG=DEBUG
    - cd terraform
    - rm -rf .terraform
    - terraform --version
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform validate
```

My `gcp-auth` job is running successfully from what I can see:

```
Authenticated with external account credentials for: [[MASKED]].
```

I've also went as far as adding in a `gsutil cp` command inside the `gcp-auth` job to make sure I can access the desired bucket as expected, which I can. I can successfully edit the contents of the bucket where my terraform statefile is stored.

I'm fairly new to gitlab CICD pipelines. Is there something I need to do to have the `gcp-auth` job tied to the `tf-stuff` job? It's like that job does not know the pipeline was previously authenticated using the service account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned by other posters, gitlab jobs run independently and dont share env variables or filesystem.  So to preserve login state betwen jobs you have to preserve the state somehow.

I wrote a blog with a working example: https://ael-computas.medium.com/gcp-workload-identity-federation-on-gitlab-passing-authentication-between-jobs-ffaa2d51be2c

I have done it like github actions is doing it, by storing (tmp) credentials as artifacts.  By setting correct env variables you should be able to "keep" the logged in state (gcp will implicitly refresh your token) without you having to create a base image containing everything.  All jobs must run the gcp_auth_before method, or extend the auth job for this to work.  and also have _auth/ artifacts preserved between jobs

In the sample below you can see that login state is preserved over two jobs, but only actuallt signing in on the first one.  I have used this together with terraform images for further steps and it works like a charm so far.

This is very early so there might be hardening required for production.

Hope this example gives you some ideas on how to solve this!

```
.gcp_auth_before: &gcp_auth_before
  - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json
  - export CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json
  - export GOOGLE_GHA_CREDS_PATH=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json
  - export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
  - export CLOUDSDK_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
  - export CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
  - export GCP_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
  - export GCLOUD_PROJECT=$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)

.gcp-auth:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - _auth/
  before_script:
    *gcp_auth_before

stages:
  - auth
  - debug

auth:
  stage: auth
  image: "google/cloud-sdk:slim"
  variables:
     SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL: "... service account email ..."
     WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER: "projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/POOL/providers/PROVIDER"
     GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT: "... project id ...."
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - _auth/
  script:
    - |
      mkdir -p _auth 
      echo "$CI_JOB_JWT_V2" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.ci_job_jwt_file
      echo "$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
      gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config \
      $WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER \
      --service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
      --service-account-token-lifetime-seconds=600 \
      --output-file=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json \
      --credential-source-file=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.ci_job_jwt_file
      gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
    - "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/_auth/.gcp_temp_cred.json"
    - "gcloud auth login --cred-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
    - gcloud auth list # DEBUG!!

debug:
  extends: .gcp-auth
  stage: debug
  image: "google/cloud-sdk:slim"
  script:
    - env
    - gcloud auth list
    - gcloud storage ls
```

Comment: I read through your blog and was FINALLY able to make mine work. Thanks so much for taking the time to write this all out. I've been stuck on this all week and it was beyond helpful! So much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your two `Gitlab` job run on a separated `pod` for the `Kubernetes` runner.

The `tf-stuff` job doesn't see the authentication done in the job `gcp-auth`.

To solve this issue, you can add the authentication code logic in a separated `Shell` script, then reuse this script in the two `Gitlab` jobs, example :

Authentication `Shell` script `gcp_authentication.sh` :

```bash
echo ${CI_JOB_JWT_V2} > .ci_job_jwt_file
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config ${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER}
      --service-account="${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"
      --output-file=.gcp_temp_cred.json
      --credential-source-file=.ci_job_jwt_file
gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json
gcloud auth list

# Check if you need to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var on `pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json
```

For the `tf-stuff`, you can create a custom `Docker` image containing `gcloud` and `Terraform` because the image `hashicorp/terraform` doesn't contains `gcloud` `cli` natively.

Your `Docker` image can be added in `Gitlab` [registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/)

Your `Gitlab` `yml` file :

```yaml
stages:
  - auth
  - validate

gcp-auth:
  stage: auth
  image: google/cloud-sdk:slim
  script:
    - . ./gcp_authentication.sh

tf-stuff:
  stage: validate
  image:
    name: yourgitlabregistry/your-custom-image:1.0.0
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
      - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  before_script:
    - . ./gcp_authentication.sh
    - export TF_LOG=DEBUG
    - cd terraform
    - rm -rf .terraform
    - terraform --version
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform validate
```

Some explanations :

- The same `Shell` script has been used in the 2 `Gitlab` jobs : `gcp_authentication.sh`
- A custom `Docker` image has been created with `Terraform` and `gcloud` `cli` in the job concerning the `Terraform` part. This image can be added to the `Gitlab` registry
- In the authentication `Shell` script, check if you need to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var on `pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json

You have to give the needed permission to your Service Account to use Gitlab with Workload Identity :

- `roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser`

You can check this [example](https://gitlab.com/guided-explorations/gcp/configure-openid-connect-in-gcp/?_gl=1%2aswh7hc%2a_ga%2aMjA5MDQ5MDExMi4xNjY5MDY4ODk0%2a_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y%2aMTY2OTA3MTYzMi4yLjAuMTY2OTA3MTYzMi4wLjAuMA..) project and the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/google_cloud/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response! Now that you explained the two jobs run on separate pods, I kind of took a similar but different approach to isolate the problem. I created a custom image containing both the gcloud-cli and terraform binaries so I can run the commands in the same pod. My job now looks like this:

Comment: ```gcp-auth:
  stage: auth
  image: registry.gitlab.com/fakename/fakeproject/gcloud-tf
  script:
    - echo ${CI_JOB_JWT_V2} > .ci_job_jwt_file
    - gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config ${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER}
      --service-account="${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"
      --output-file=.gcp_temp_cred.json
      --credential-source-file=.ci_job_jwt_file
    - gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    - gcloud config set project fake-project
    - gcloud auth list
    - cd terraform
    - terraform init
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I can't get that output to format properly. But I'm still getting the same error when this all runs inside a single pod:

`Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions`

If I put the following line in here it succeeds so I know I have access to the bucket. It's just terraform that fails for some reason.

`gsutil cp gs://fakebucket/testfile gs://fakebucket/testfile2`

Comment: As I proposed in my comment, can you also add `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable targeting on the Service account temporary key file path ?

Comment: I had initially put that in but had a different error:


```Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: Get "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/fake-bucket/o?alt=json&delimiter=%2F&pageToken=&prefix=state%2Ffake-project%2F&prettyPrint=false&projection=full&versions=false": oauth2/google: unable to generate access token: Post "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/[MASKED]:generateAccessToken": oauth2/google: failed to open credential file ".ci_job_jwt_file"```


Haven't had a chance to do much digging on this one yet though.

Comment: Have you given the needed permission to your service account :  `workload Identity` user ? 
I edited my answer to share with you some links to Gitlab documentation.
You can also check this link : https://cloud-architecture-design.medium.com/using-gitlab-ci-with-gcp-workload-identity-federation-8b80bec99c0b

Comment: Yes, my service account has the `owner` and `Workload Identity User' roles granted to it. My openid terraform configs are identical to the sample project you posted. I think I may have originally copied from the same thing.

I just ran the same code without using a remote statefile and it succeeds though so I think it might be related to that. My remote statefile is in the same project though so it's not clear to me why it wouldn't have access. Even if I revert my terraform code to the original state with it split into two jobs, it succeeds as long as I'm not using a remote statefile.

Comment: Actually on 2nd look using a local statefile only delays the error. I get it when I do a `terraform apply` as opposed to `terraform init` when using a remote statefile which makes sense because it just changes the spot where it actually has to make updates in GCP. So I'm still stumped on this one.

Comment: I wonder if there is a permission missing on Cloud Storage ?

Comment: It sure looks like it anyway. I've granted everything I can think of though. In IAM, the service account has the following roles granted to it:

```Owner
Storage Admin,
Storage Object Admin,
Workload Identity User```

The bucket itself has the following roles granted to the service account as well:

```Storage Admin,
Storage Legacy Bucket Owner,
Storage Legacy Object Owner,
Storage Object Admin```